# Extracting certain text between two characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a `nvarchar` string from which I need to extract certain text from between characters.

Example: `1.abc.5,m001-1-Exit,822-FName-18001233321--2021-09-23 13:53:10 Thursday-m001-1-Exit-Swipe,Card NO:    822User ID:     FNameName:  18001233321Dept:    Read Date:  2021-09-23 13:53:10 ThursdayAddr:   m001-1-ExitStatus:  Swipe,07580ec2000002a52E917D0000000000372BA56E11010000`

What I need:

```
| Name     | Phone Number   |    
| -------- | -------------- |    
| FName    | 1800123321     |
```

My Attempt:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(col, LEN(LEFT(col, CHARINDEX ('-', col))) + 1, LEN(col) - LEN(LEFT(col,      CHARINDEX ('-', col))) - LEN(RIGHT(col, LEN(col) - CHARINDEX ('-', col))) - 1);
```

Comment: Sorry! Changed them ; Tried `SELECT SUBSTRING(col, LEN(LEFT(col, CHARINDEX ('-', col))) + 1, LEN(col) - LEN(LEFT(col, 
    CHARINDEX ('-', col))) - LEN(RIGHT(col, LEN(col) - CHARINDEX ('-', col))) - 1);` no avail

Comment: And is it always of the format `FName-XXXXXXXX-`? There are loads of examples out there of how to extract parts of a string.

Comment: Yes its always like that

Comment: Is your example nvarchar string really full of words running into each other (forex: "FNameName") and long stretches of white space, or is that a formatting mishap?

Comment: 1. Is "FName" just a stand-in for a first name, or a string literal that always appears in the string?  2. what part of the string do you want to try to extract the phone number from?

Comment: Yes, thats how its displayed in the table. FName is a stand-in for the first name. I wanted to extract the phone number from in between the first `-`'s that surround both the first FName and the Phone number. The other data is pretty unimportant to me.

Comment: Can you extract everything you need from the stretch between commas 2 and 3? (I'm trying to figure out how to home in on the relevant segment!)

Comment: @AnnL. Thanks for your quick answers!

Comment: @DaleK Done, thanks for your help

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?  If you are at 2016 or later, there's the `STRING_SPLIT` function, which will help you _immensely_.  (See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @bloomerv did the answer below help you?

Comment: @DaleK Hey, I the Fname doesnt stay constant it was just a fill in for First Name. So that value would change. But it pulls the phone number perfectly in the blank column.

Comment: @DaleK Also, how would one change the values from going string by string to pull the data from the column of the table? My column name in the table is `f_EventDesc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way:

- Use `patindex` to find "FName-"
- Remove the start of the string up until and including "FName-"
- Use `patindex` to find "--"
- Remove the rest of the string from and including "--"

You can consolidate the query down to one line, but you'll find yourself repeating parts of the logic - which I like to avoid. And calculating one thing at a time makes it easier to debug.

```
select
  A.Col
  , B.StringStart
  , C.NewString
  , patindex('%--%',C.NewString) NewStringEnd
  , substring(C.NewString,1,patindex('%--%',C.NewString)-1) -- <- Required Result
from (
  values
  (N'1.abc.5,m001-1-Exit,822-FName-18001233321--2021-09-23 13:53:10 Thursday-m001-1-Exit-Swipe,Card NO:    822User ID:     FNameName:  18001233321Dept:    Read Date:  2021-09-23 13:53:10 ThursdayAddr:   m001-1-ExitStatus:  Swipe,07580ec2000002a52E917D0000000000372BA56E11010000')
) A (Col)
cross apply (
  values
  (patindex('%FName-%',Col))
) B (StringStart)
cross apply (
  values
  (substring(A.Col,B.StringStart+6,len(A.Col)-B.StringStart-6))
) C (NewString);
```