# Find and replace by pattern

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, replace

I have a table that has a column like the one below

```
url
----------------
dir=mp3\cat152AB&amp;fileName=file-01.mp3
dir=mp3\cat2500DfDD00&amp;fileName=file-02.mp3
dir=mp3\cat4500f0655&amp;fileName=file-03.mp3
...
```

How can I delete extra strings and arrange the fields as follows in SQL Server.

```
url
----------------
file-01
file-02
file-03
...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting certain text between two characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69307538/extracting-certain-text-between-two-characters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use charindex and substring :

```
SELECT substring ('dir=mp3\cat152AB&amp;fileName=file-01.mp3', CHARINDEX('fileName=', 'dir=mp3\cat152AB&amp;fileName=file-01.mp3') +9 ,  
 LEN('dir=mp3\cat152AB&amp;fileName=file-01.mp3')-CHARINDEX('fileName=', 'dir=mp3\cat152AB&amp;fileName=file-01.mp3') 
) AS MatchPosition;
```

Comment: Of course if you use `cross apply` you can avoid repeating the same calculations multiple times.

Comment: IMHO, very poor choice for an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

`CHARINDEX` and `SUBSTRING` can help you, please check the example:

```
select substring (field, charindex (';fileName=', field) + len (';fileName='), len (field) - len ('.mp3') + 1 - charindex (';fileName=', field) - len (';fileName='))
from (
select 'dir=mp3\cat152AB&amp;fileName=file-01.mp3' field union all
select 'dir=mp3\cat2500DfDD00&amp;fileName=file-02.mp3' union all
select 'dir=mp3\cat4500f0655&amp;fileName=file-03.mp3'
) a
```

Comment: Of course if you use `cross apply` you can avoid repeating the same calculations multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

The information you want always seems to be the 11th to 5th characters before the end of the string.  I would suggest a simple solution:

```
select left(right(url, 11), 7)
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=75e0a63acbe0a578d65cf42e782c7a2f) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following method.

It is using tokenization via XML/XQuery.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, url VARCHAR(255));
INSERT INTO @tbl (url) VALUES
('dir=mp3\cat152AB&amp;fileName=file-01.mp3'),
('dir=mp3\cat2500DfDD00&amp;fileName=file-02.mp3'),
('dir=mp3\cat4500f0655&amp;fileName=file-03.mp3');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = '=';

SELECT id, url
    , LEFT(x, CHARINDEX('.', x) - 1) AS Result
FROM @tbl
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
            REPLACE(url, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
            ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c)
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES (c.value('(/root/r[last()]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'))) AS t2(x);
```

**Output**

```
+----+------------------------------------------------+---------+
| id |                      url                       | Result  |
+----+------------------------------------------------+---------+
|  1 | dir=mp3\cat152AB&amp;fileName=file-01.mp3      | file-01 |
|  2 | dir=mp3\cat2500DfDD00&amp;fileName=file-02.mp3 | file-02 |
|  3 | dir=mp3\cat4500f0655&amp;fileName=file-03.mp3  | file-03 |
+----+------------------------------------------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I know we have an accepted answer but I wanted to chime in with another simple, high-performing solution that addresses file names and file extensions with various lengths. For fun I included a parameter that allows you to include the file extension if you choose.

```
--==== Easily Consumable Sample Data
DECLARE @link TABLE ([url] VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE);
INSERT  @link VALUES ('dir=mp3\cat152AB&amp;fileName=file-01.mp3'),
                     ('dir=mp3\cat2500DfDD00&amp;fileName=file-02.mp3'),
                     ('dir=mp3\cat4500f0655&amp;fileName=file-03.mp3'),
                     ('dir=mp3\cat4500f0655&amp;fileName=file-999.mp3'),
                     ('dir=mp3\cat4500d9997&amp;fileName=file-0021.prodigi');

--==== Allows you to determine if you want the file extension
DECLARE @exclude BIT=1;

SELECT      l.[url], TheFile = SUBSTRING(l.[url], s.Pos, s.Ln-s.Pos- ((@exclude*(fl.Ln)-1)))
FROM        @link AS l
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(l.[url])))) AS fl(Ln)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('fileName=',l.[url])+9, LEN(l.[url]))) AS s(Pos,Ln);
```

@exclude=1 returns:

```
url                                                   TheFile
----------------------------------------------------- --------------
dir=mp3\cat152AB&amp;fileName=file-01.mp3             file-01
dir=mp3\cat2500DfDD00&amp;fileName=file-02.mp3        file-02
dir=mp3\cat4500d9997&amp;fileName=file-0021.prodigi   file-0021
dir=mp3\cat4500f0655&amp;fileName=file-03.mp3         file-03
dir=mp3\cat4500f0655&amp;fileName=file-999.mp3        file-999
```

@exclude=0 returns:

```
url                                                   TheFile
----------------------------------------------------- --------------
dir=mp3\cat152AB&amp;fileName=file-01.mp3             file-01.mp3
dir=mp3\cat2500DfDD00&amp;fileName=file-02.mp3        file-02.mp3
dir=mp3\cat4500d9997&amp;fileName=file-0021.prodigi   file-0021.prodigi
dir=mp3\cat4500f0655&amp;fileName=file-03.mp3         file-03.mp3
dir=mp3\cat4500f0655&amp;fileName=file-999.mp3        file-999.mp3
```